# How to install the man page for displaying the structure info of host_ent and in_addr?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

```
user@ubuntu:~/Documents/C$ man host_ent
No manual entry for host_ent
```

How to install the manpage for host_ent or  in_addr under ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct`s are not documented in their own man pages in Linux, but rather as part of a man page in section 2/3/3p. The package containing the `gethostbyname(3)` and `inet(3)` man pages is `manpages-dev`.

Comment: May you tell me whether there is a standard way to know which man page I should look for? For example, sometimes I have to use man inet while other time I have to use man 3 inet. Or simply, I just have to use brute-force to find the information.

Comment: I cheat and use Google. >.>